# Curl returning empty when using working proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I am trying to use curl through a proxy, when I dont use a proxy it works fine but if I use a proxy it returns null, no error messages or anything.
I have already tried other opened questions but their answers are inconclusive.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://dynupdate.no-ip.com/ip.php';
$proxy = '122.117.225.161:8080';
//$proxyauth = 'user:pass';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);     
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 

$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($curl_scraped_page); 

?>
```

The proxy there is a free working proxy (I manually checked), I have also tried it with a private proxy (I used the user:pass authentication method) but still returns null.

Any information will be helpful.
Thanks!